# Cronjobs after each other

Tags: cron

I have a lot of php-scripts which I would like to execute as cronjob. It´s important that those scripts are executed in the right order and are not running at the same time. How can I set up cronjobs which run after each other?

Comment: use a script which executes one after another or use a separate directory, put all scripts there, where as the names represent the order, and use `run-parts`

Answer (score 7):

Each cron job runs when it's scheduled to run, regardless of whether any other cron jobs happen to be running.

Just make a cron job that executes several commands sequentially:

```
* * * * * command1; command2; command3
```

The command (in this case `command1; command2; command3`) is executed by `/bin/sh` (or by a shell you can specify by setting `SHELL` in your crontab). `/bin/sh`, or any shell worthy of the name, knows how to execute commands sequentially.

If there are a lot of commands you can put them into a shell script and execute that from `cron`.

Comment: I´m opening hundreds of urls with the "open" command. The problem is that my browser opens them in foreground. So basically I cannot use my laptop anymore because the browser is blocking everything. How can I open an online php-script in background?

Comment: What is the `open` command? On my system, `/bin/open` opens a virtual terminal. What OS are you using? You might want to open a new question; opening a PHP script in the background isn't related to cron.